# Mongodb query to check if a particular field is not null ( aggregation)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have queries like

```
{
"title": "sjncx",
"desciption": "cknxk jckd",
"price": "29.99",
"stock": "3",
...
}
```

I need to filter data if the title `is not empty`.( title exists and not null). And also `is empty` like ~ `title: ""` ~ ( so title exists but empty)

I tried for `is not empty`:

`{'title': {'$ne': 'null'}}`

I tried for `is empty`:

`{'title': {'$type': 10}}`

That doesn't work. What would be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in` to cover both cases empty and null :

```
{
  "title": {
    "$nin": [null, ""]
  }
}
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FVpudwogue0)

Answer (score 2):

Use **$and** which is very expressive

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "title": {
        "$ne": null
      }
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "$ne": ""
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

You will just set your condition there.
The  [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/V13mnmf6xGE